# Passing an empty string in Java action argument in Oozie

Tags: java, oozie

I want to pass an empty string ("") argument in my Java action in Oozie (in workflow.xml). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about to create a dummy variable which value is empty string?
I didn't tried, may that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression:

```
${firstNotNull("", "")}
```